# Can anybody post me an example, How to show json url data along with image in a fragment list view?

Tags: android, json, android-fragments

Hey guys I am trying to show json data from remote url contain image and text and want to show in a fragment? Can anybody post me an example code or refer to a best one tutorial. I already have googled but could not find a right solution as I am looking for.

Here is my MainActivity

```
package com.androidbelieve.drawerwithswipetabs;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    NavigationView mNavigationView;
    FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /**
         *Setup the DrawerLayout and NavigationView
         */

             mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
             mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.shitstuff) ;

        /**
         * Lets inflate the very first fragment
         * Here , we are inflating the TabFragment as the first Fragment
         */

             mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
             mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
             mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new TabFragment()).commit();
        /**
         * Setup click events on the Navigation View Items.
         */

             mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
             @Override
             public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();



                 if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_sent) {
                     FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                     fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new SentFragment()).commit();

                 }

                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_inbox) {
                    FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView,new TabFragment()).commit();
                }

                 return false;
            }

        });

        /**
         * Setup Drawer Toggle of the Toolbar
         */

                android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout, toolbar,R.string.app_name,
                R.string.app_name);

                mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

                mDrawerToggle.syncState();

    }
}
```

Now I want to show the PrimaryFragment Like;

```
package com.androidbelieve.drawerwithswipetabs;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.androidbelieve.drawerwithswipetabs.model.AndroidVersion;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class PrimaryFragment extends AppCompatActivity implements LoadJSONTask.Listener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private ListView mListView;

    public static final String URL = "https://api.learn2crack.com/android/jsonandroid/";

    private List<HashMap<String, String>> mAndroidMapList = new ArrayList<>();

    private static final String KEY_VER = "ver";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_API = "api";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        new LoadJSONTask(this).execute(URL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaded(List<AndroidVersion> androidList) {

        for (AndroidVersion android : androidList) {

            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

            map.put(KEY_VER, android.getVer());
            map.put(KEY_NAME, android.getName());
            map.put(KEY_API, android.getApi());

            mAndroidMapList.add(map);
        }

        loadListView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onError() {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Error !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

        Toast.makeText(this, mAndroidMapList.get(i).get(KEY_NAME),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private void loadListView() {

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(PrimaryFragment.this, mAndroidMapList, R.layout.list_item,
                new String[] { KEY_VER, KEY_NAME, KEY_API },
                new int[] { R.id.version,R.id.name, R.id.api });

        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

And the Logcat is:

```
PrimaryFragment cannot be converted to Fragment
```

Thank you.

Comment: Read this http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/

Comment: Need to load json data in fragment. How?

Comment: make a call from fragment and get back the jsonresponse in fragment itself.

Comment: Can you write me steps and example?

Comment: No.First read the link and try to implement the same then only you will get these basic things. Code more..

Comment: `PrimaryFragment' needs to extend in `Fragment` not `AppCompatActivity `
and in fragment you cannot create view in `onCreate` but you have to `@Override`  `onCreateView` method in android

Comment: Convert it but not able to get rid from error.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get data Asynchronously and then parse date from json to respective objects then show it in their respective views and after getting json and parsing it you have to download images Asynchronously you can learn it from [here](https://www.learn2crack.com/2013/11/listview-from-json-example.html)

Comment: I need the example in fragment please.

Comment: But how ? That's my question ? I am new to android and can't complete What I need.

Comment: @JagadishDulal have you follow the code i suggested ?

Comment: Yes, but I need it in a fragment, I already have a MainActivity.java but I want the main activity code in a FirstFragment. Can you write me step by step example?

Comment: @JagadishDulal update your question with your code and logcat